# Meteor: Meteor.setInterval not working as I want

Tags: node.js, meteor

Right now I'm working on a project where I have to use Meteor.setInterval to repeatedly execute the code after fetching data using request package. This code works just one time but doesn't go to the subsequent executions. The following code below will help you understand that how I'm doing this.

```
request("http://link-from-where-data-is-fetched",function(err,data){


          var flag1 = true;
          var flag2 = false;
          var flag3 = false;
          var flag4 = false;

          Meteor.setInterval(function callfunc(){


            if(flag1 == true){

                flag1 = false;
                flag2 = true;

                // other code is here

            }else if(flag2 == true){

                flag2 = false;
                flag3 = true;

                // other code is here

            }else if(flag3 == true){

               flag3 = false;
               flag4 = true;

               // other code is here

            }else if(flag4 == true){

               flag4 = false;

               // other code is here
            }

          },20*1000);

});
```

Can anybody help me why such code is not working properly?
The above example code is used in server side in my project.

Comment: How do you know that it runs one time and not subsequently?

Comment: Because im outputing the data on console. So any suggestion why this code is running only one time.

Comment: Documentation for [`Deps`](http://docs.meteor.com/#computation_stop) suggests that the _enclosing_ computation might be getting `stop`ped. That may _stop_ all internal computations as well. Could that be the case?

Comment: No I'm working with Meteor.setInterval() which only runs just for one time.